# How do I use the morelikethis feature in solr

Tags: c#, solr, lucene, solrnet, morelikethis

I want to find all the documents that is similar to a specific document within solr. How to i do this in solr? I have looked i the documentation and it only explains how to find documents using a query phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [MoreLikeThis handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThisHandler). The wiki page has several usage examples.

In SolrNet, support for the MLT handler is still an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=143). A [patch has been submitted](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/pull/14) but I'm not so keen on the implementation. I encourage you to try it out and give us feedback!

Comment: I have updated my post. Maybe this will give some insight. yes I am using the morelikethishandler but still getting the error.

Comment: @Luke101: you completely changed the question from "how do I use MLT" to "I'm getting this error using MLT". This is **bad netiquette**, as you're now **forcing** me to change my answer or delete it altogether. In short, it's a waste of time for me. Instead of doing this, you should revert your changes and create a new question. In the future, always post all details relevant to your specific issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I offended you. I thought this was an easy fix since I followed all of the solr documentation. I just needed a quick example mlt query to verify I was doing things right. I will delete my vote so you can delete your answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Luke101 : it's not offensive, if you revert the changes and post a new question I'll be happy to answer it. My point is, they're two very different questions. Stackoverflow is not a mailing list, it's a Q&A website.

Comment: Hi Mauricio, I have made the changes and re-posted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891518/what-is-wrong-with-this-solr-query. Thanks for your time