# Solr MoreLikeThis /mlt handler returns a 404 error

Tags: c#, lucene, solr, solrnet

I want to find all the documents that is similar to a specific document within solr. I have installed solr and made some queries. The query I am trying to make gives an error which I cannot make out or research on the internet. Can you give me some light on this? I am using solrnet client but if solrnet is not appropriate for this type of query I will gladly use pure solr and read the XML.

Here is the query I am using:

> http://192.168.1.10:8080/solr/mlt?q=id:12&mlt.fl=content&mlt.mindf=1&mlt.mintf=1

here is my schema xml here

```
 <fields>
  <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
 </fields>
```

Here is the error I am receiving:
[image]

Comment: Can you send _any_ queries to your SOLR instance ? What URL (example) works ?

Comment: Yes, I can send queries just fine. But when I try to use the MoreLikeThis handler it gives the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you haven't registered the MLT handler in solrconfig.xml. A simple registration looks like this:

```
<requestHandler name="/mlt" class="org.apache.solr.handler.MoreLikeThisHandler"/>
```

Comment: whoa..this really worked. I can't believe it. I have the the solr book and follwed the directions but i think it needs to be updated. Thanks alot man - I really appreciate it.